# Diffusion process with "centering" drift

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Consider a diffusion process which has a drift that pushes it towards some fixed value.

Specifically, consider the example of a MLE estimator for a Bernoulli random variable, given by $\mu_t = \frac{C_t}{t}$ where $C_t$ is the count of successes. We know $\mu_t \rightarrow p$ where $p$ is the Bernoulli parameter, i.e. $C_t \sim \text{Bernoulli}(p)$.

The drift of a process is defined as $\lim_{dt\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{dt}\mathbb{E}[\mu_{t+dt} - \mu_t | \mu_t] $.

Then, whenever $\mu_t < p$, the drift would be positive, pushing $\mu_t$ toward $p$, and vice versa.

In the continuum limit of this process, i.e. $dC_t = \sqrt{dt}$ and $dt \rightarrow 0$, this is a diffusion process. How can we define the drift? I believe it should be piecewise constant, with value depending on whether $\mu_t > p$ or $\mu_t < p$.

Comment: This question should either be posted on physics site or should be made mathematician friendly by editing.

Comment: How do you suggest I edit it? @xax

Comment: Write all information in mathematical expressions. I don't understand anything even if you talk about Bernoulli bias or drift and diffusion.

Comment: @xax these are pretty standard terminologies in stochastic processes, but I can clarify.

Comment: I don't understand how your drift is meant to be defined here since to me $C_t$ exists in discrete time.

Comment: @Ian right, I am taking the continuous limit as one would when deriving Brownian motion from the Bernoulli random walk. I.e. the reward size is $\sqrt{dt}$.

Comment: You cannot do that in the same way in the presence of a drift. You must isolate the drift and the diffusion and rescale separately for both. Otherwise the mean of the process "diverges instantly".

Comment: Actually sorry, I jumped to a conclusion; things don't necessarily break so spectacularly in this "mean-restoring drift" situation, because "the drifts tend to cancel over time".

Comment: @Ian you're right, I didn't think about that and will try to derive it from scratch, but what do you mean by the canceling of drifts? I found that the overall expected value of the drift is nonzero which was surprising to me.

Comment: The mean increment is positive when $\mu_t<p$ and negative when $\mu_t>p$. It is *not* piecewise constant as you suggested but still it has this property. This means that a naive continuum limit does not just instantly explode.

Comment: Anyway, to get the associated drift-diffusion process, you can use Kramers-Moyal expansion.

Comment: @Ian thanks, I'll try it! Will update the question if issues arise.

Comment: @Ian Now I am getting more confused. I thought the Taylor series on the master equation would be simple but [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/245026/diffusion-coefficient-for-asymmetric-biased-random-walk/291398) discusses the need to separate the drift and diffusion, as you mentioned, but I'm not following all of it.

Comment: @900edges Let me know if my answer made sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first off you must work with the Poisson process with jump rate $p$ instead of directly with $C_t$. This is a reasonable assumption for large time, by basically the same logic as the Poisson approximation to the binomial. I'll call that Poisson process $C_t$ from here out.

The main idea is that the Poisson process $C_t$ itself cannot be described by a diffusion process directly at all. One must instead work with a process with at least small drift if not zero drift, because just $C_t$ when converted to a continuum limit in a naive way would either be deterministic (because $O(t/dt)$ steps of magnitude $dt$ occur and the law of large numbers kicks in) or diverge instantly (because $O(t/dt)$ steps of magnitude $(dt)^{1/2}$ occur and they tend not to cancel out because of the drift).

In this context it makes sense to achieve the approximation by defining a time scale $T \gg 1$ and examining $c_\tau=C_{T \tau}=T \mu_\tau + T^{1/2} \sigma_\tau$ where $\mu_\tau$ is deterministic and $\sigma_\tau$ is random. Neither can depend explicitly on $T$ (if they do then our scaling was wrong).

This is a kind of analogue of van Kampen system size expansion where the large parameter is forced in by stretching out the time scale. (Note that this focus on large time is necessary, there is no way that the short time dynamics can be resolved by a diffusion process in any reasonable sense.)

In this case $\mu_\tau=p\tau$ necessarily, and then you are left to perform Taylor expansion on the master equation for the evolution of $\sigma_\tau=T^{-1/2} \left ( c_\tau-T\mu_\tau \right )=T^{-1/2} c_\tau - T^{1/2} p \tau$ in powers of the small parameter $T^{-1/2}$ in order to isolate the "microscopic drift" (if there is any) and the diffusion inside of $c_\tau$. It looks like you get that the first moment is just zero while the second moment is $T^{-1}$ times the second moment of the increment distribution of $c_\tau$ which is $pT$. So for $T \gg 1$ and $t=T\tau$ where $\tau$ is of order $1$, we have that the PDF of $\sigma_\tau$ asymptotically exists and evolves as

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau}=\frac{p}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}.$$

Consequently the overall process $C_t$ behaves like $pt+\sqrt{p} B_t$ where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion, for large time.

Remarks:

- This implies that the one-dimensional distribution of $C_t$ is asymptotically $N(pt,pt)$ distributed. This is consistent with what we know for CLT for the Poisson distribution. It's not exactly consistent with what we know for CLT for the binomial (which would tell us the variance should be $pqt$ not $pt$), but that error was already committed in passing to the Poisson process approximation in the first place.
- You could do the procedure over by writing $C_t=t-(t-C_t)$ and then starting from scratch with that. This will be more accurate than what I wrote here if $p>1/2$. (This is the analogue of the Poisson approximation to the binomial in the $p \to 1^-$ limit.)
- Keep in mind that it does not make sense to say that the one dimensional distribution of $C_t$ *converges* to $N(pt,pt)$ as $t \to \infty$; this is the same situation as with CLT, if you want convergence you need to shift and rescale.

My main source here is Gardiner *Handbook of Stochastic Methods* Chapter 7.

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thank you for the thoughtful response! To be honest, everything past the second paragraph is over my head and I will need to spend some more time on it. (I don't understand $c_\tau$ and the form $T\mu_\tau + T^{1/2} \sigma^2_\tau$. Is $T_\tau$ some kind of indexing of times in $[0,t]$? )

Comment: @900edges $c_\tau$ is just $C_t$ as a function of the rescaled time $\tau$. There's no $T_\tau$, it is just $t=T\tau$ as the definition of $\tau$. Anyway, decomposing $X_t=\Omega \mu_t + \Omega^{1/2} \sigma_t$ where $\Omega$ is a large parameter is the normal procedure in system size expansion. Basically this is a lot like the CLT rescaling, $\Omega^{1/2} \sigma_t$ is like $n \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\Omega \mu_t$ is like $n \mu$.